# "Missing credentials in config" error when using amplify Auth.currentCredentials()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

We are using Amplify to manage the coginto credentials and once a while we will get this error when using the credentials: 
***Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1***

It does not happen often, happens once a day for us. Very hard to trigger.

The way we use it is like this:

```
const getDocumentClient = (): Promise<DocumentClient> =>
    Auth.currentCredentials().then(
        (credentials) =>
            new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
                region: REGION,
                credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
            })
    )

export const getItemFromSettingsTable = async (
    Key: KeyType
): Promise<DocumentClient.GetItemOutput> => {
    const params = {
        TableName: xxx,
        Key,
    }

    const client = await getDocumentClient()

    return client.get(params).promise()
}
```

According to the stacktrace, we are getting the error when call the getItemFromSettingsTable.

It seems to be a race condition issue, since it usually does not happen.

Anyone run into this before?

Thanks.